# What surface is represented by $\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{a} = \mathrm{const.}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products

> What surface is represented by $\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{a} = \mathrm{const.}$ that is described if $\mathbf{a}$ is a vector of constant magnitude and direction from the origin and $\mathbf{r}$ is the position vector to the point $P(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ on the surface?

My approach was to assume that $\mathbf{a}$ is a constant vector. Then I wrote
$$
\mathbf{a} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\xi_1\\
\xi_2\\
\xi_3
\end{pmatrix}\quad,\quad
\mathbf{r} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}\quad.
$$
Then I proceed to take the dot product: $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{r} = \xi_1x_1+\xi_2 x_2+\xi_3x_3 = c$ for some constant $c$. This is the equation of a plane.

Is my solution correct? Is there any other way to do this using the alternative definition of the dot product, i.e, $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{r} = ar\cos\theta$?

Comment: You are correct. Perhaps you could be more precise, and say that the surface is the plane through the point $(c/\xi_1,0,0)$ with normal vector $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: Think about projection. The vectors with a given projection on $\mathbf a$ form a plane orthogonal to $\mathbf a$.